# Virtualbox Python API VirtualBoxManager()

Tags: python, virtualbox

I am wondering why when I create VirtualBoxManager object like that:

```
# This is a VirtualBox COM/XPCOM API client, no data needed.
wrapper = VirtualBoxManager(None, None)

# Get the VirtualBox manager
mgr  = wrapper.mgr
# Get the global VirtualBox object
vbox = wrapper.vbox
```

The above code is from http://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Main/webservice/samples/python/clienttest.py

whats the difference between wrapper and mgr?
They are both VirtualBoxManager objects!! Why bother getting if from the wrapper? and why wrapper (VirtualBoxManager object) contains an object mgr (VirtualBoxManager object)?

When I try my own code

```
wrapper = VirtualBoxManager("WEBSERVICE", {"url": "", "username": "", "password": ""})
mgr = wrapper.mgr
print str(mgr)                                                                                                                                        
print str(wrapper)
```

The output is the same:

```
<vboxapi.VirtualBoxManager object at 0x7f2a9c551050>
<vboxapi.VirtualBoxManager object at 0x7f2a9c551050>
```

so it means they reference the same place!!

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox using some kind of [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model).

One object may have several different interfaces. In Pure C or C++ some interfaces have the same address in the memory and some not. It depends on the implementation and compiler interface.

Also worth considering that the wrapper for Python can be dynamic (aggregated) and in the run-time to determine which of the user interface of treatment was.